# How do I activate a plugin while testing?

Tags: testing, integration-tests

I want to make sure my plugin works while another plugin is activated:

```
    public function test_registration_3() {
        activate_plugin( 'new-user-approve/new-user-approve.php', '', false, true );
        $errors = register_new_user ( 'newuser', 'newuser@example.com' );
        $this->assertIsInt( $errors );
        wp_delete_user( $errors );
        deactivate_plugins( 'new-user-approve/new-user-approve.php' );
    }
```

This isn't working. I tried the solution at [PHPUnit test plugin activation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218713/phpunit-test-plugin-activation) but it didn't work. My plugin is still behaving as if the other plugin is not active.